# How do you maintain an index when you sort two index synced (paired) arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I have two arrays that I need to keep the index pairs together:

```
arr1 = [17,9,8,20,14,16]
arr2 = [27,13,10,10,24,18]
```

I want to return them both as:

```
arr1 = [8,9,14,16,17,20]
arr2 = [10,13,24,18,27,10]
```

I've tried `arr1.each.zip(arr2.each).sort` which gives me: `[[8, 10], [9, 13], [14, 24], [16, 18], [17, 27], [20, 10]]`. I was hoping there was a faster way that also maintains the arrays.

I then went on to `transpose` which got me my nested arrays but then I just can't seem to get the map right to fix my original arrays.

```
arr1.each.zip(arr2.each).sort.transpose.map {
 |a_1| a1.map { |a_2| arr1 = a_1; arr2 = a_2  }
}
```

I also feel like there should be a simpler less time and space complex solution to this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close.

```
arr1 = [17,9,8,20,14,16]
arr2 = [27,13,10,10,24,18]

arr1, arr2 = arr1.zip(arr2).sort.transpose
  #=> [[8, 9, 14, 16, 17, 20], [10, 13, 24, 18, 27, 10]] 
arr1
  #=> [8, 9, 14, 16, 17, 20] 
arr2
  #=> [10, 13, 24, 18, 27, 10]
```

Note that if `arr1` contains duplicates the corresponding values in `arr2` will break ties in sorting.

Another way, if you only wish to sort on `arr1`, is the following.

```
sorted_indices = arr1.each_index.sort_by { |i| arr1[i] }
  #=> [2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 3] 
arr1 = arr1.values_at(*sorted_indices)
  #=> [8, 9, 14, 16, 17, 20] 
arr2 = arr2.values_at(*sorted_indices)
  #=> [10, 13, 24, 18, 27, 10]
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: I tried to solve this problem, I arrived at your first solution. And I started seeing your answer, your first solution exactly resembles like mine. And then looked at your second one, that's awesome!

Comment: `arr1.zip(arr2).sort_by(&:first).transpose` resolves the dups issue.